# Get duplicates in object and merge the value

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I have a pretty simple question I just can't figure it out.

I want to merge all duplicated objects and keep track of how many duplicates I have.

Here is my input:

```
[
  { w: 'abc', c: 1 },
  { w: 'abc', c: 1 },
  { w: 'abc', c: 1 },
  { w: 'a', c: 1 },
  { w: 'a', c: 1 },
  { w: 'b', c: 1 },
  { w: 'c', c: 1 }
]
```

Here the output I'd like to have,

```
[ 
  { w: 'abc', c: 3 },
  { w: 'a', c: 2 },
  { w: 'b', c: 1 },
  { w: 'c', c: 1 }
]
```

`_.union()` works to delete the duplicates but I can't keep track of them.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain the methods of underscore and group the items by `w` and then map new object with the sum of the wanted values.

```js
var data = [{ w: 'abc', c: 1 }, { w: 'abc', c: 1 }, { w: 'abc', c: 1 }, { w: 'a', c: 1 }, { w: 'a', c: 1 }, { w: 'b', c: 1 }, { w: 'c', c: 1 }],
    result = _
        .chain(data)
        .groupBy('w')
        .map((array, w) => ({ w, c: _.reduce(array, (s, { c }) => s + c, 0) }))
        .value();

    console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer that's exactly what i needed <3

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `O(n)` solution for that result using plain JavaScript.

```js
var arr = [ { w: 'abc', c: 1 },
{ w: 'abc', c: 1 },
{ w: 'abc', c: 1 },
{ w: 'a', c: 1 },
{ w: 'a', c: 1 },
{ w: 'b', c: 1 },
{ w: 'c', c: 1 }];

var tempObj = {};
arr.forEach((obj)=>{
  if(tempObj[obj.w]){
    tempObj[obj.w].c += obj.c
  } else {
    tempObj[obj.w] = {
      w: obj.w,
      c : obj.c
    }
  }
});
var resArray = Object.values(tempObj);
console.log(resArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map and reduce this to get the data you are looking for:

```js
const data = [ { w: 'abc', c: 1 },
{ w: 'abc', c: 1 },
{ w: 'abc', c: 1 },
{ w: 'a', c: 1 },
{ w: 'a', c: 1 },
{ w: 'b', c: 1 },
{ w: 'c', c: 1 }]


const output = data
  .map(item => item.w)
  .reduce((prev, curr) => ({
    ...prev,
    [curr]: (prev[curr] || 0) + 1
  }), {})
  
const correctFormat = Object.keys(output)
  .map(key => ({
    w: key,
    c: output[key]
  }))
  
console.dir(correctFormat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Array.protoype.reduce` method. You can pass an empty object literal as the second parameter and add keys to it based on the `w` property of each array element. For each element of the array, check if the key already exists - if it doesn't, set the count to 1 - if it does, increment the count by 1:

```js
var a = [{
    w: 'abc',
    c: 1
  },
  {
    w: 'abc',
    c: 1
  },
  {
    w: 'abc',
    c: 1
  },
  {
    w: 'a',
    c: 1
  },
  {
    w: 'a',
    c: 1
  },
  {
    w: 'b',
    c: 1
  },
  {
    w: 'c',
    c: 1
  }
];

var b = a.reduce((accum, el) => {
  if (accum[el.w]) {
    accum[el.w] = accum[el.w] + 1;
  } else {
    accum[el.w] = 1;
  }
  return accum;
}, {});

console.log(b);
```

This is a standard JavaScript solution - it doesn't need to take advantage of underscore features.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take using [`_.countBy()`](https://underscorejs.org/#countBy) and [`_.map`](https://underscorejs.org/#map):

```js
var data = [ { w: 'abc', c: 1 },
    { w: 'abc', c: 1 },
    { w: 'abc', c: 1 },
    { w: 'a', c: 1 },
    { w: 'a', c: 1 },
    { w: 'b', c: 1 },
    { w: 'c', c: 1 }]


var result = _
  .chain(data)
  .countBy('w')
  .map(function(v, k) {  
    return { w: k, c: v }
  })
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```